# What is the point of the symlink to com.apple.PeoplePicker.plist?

Tags: iphone

Any Xcode project I create from scratch always contain either a sym link to the com.apple.AddressBook.plist file or to com.apple.PeoplePicker.plist in the folder:

> Application Support/iPhone
>   Simulator/(SDK
>   Version)/Applications/(GUID)/Library/Preferences

Anyone know why this is and how do I go about the app never creating this?

It seems to get created after I run the app in the simulator and always comes back no matter what I do.

What purpose does this link serve?

Comment: Why do you want to get rid of it? If Apple put it there I assume they have a good reason and a symlink isn’t much in the way of inefficiency.

Answer (score 1):

The point of the symlink to com.apple.PeoplePicker.plist is to provide default sorting behavior for the PeoplePicker; when picking recipients for email message.

Reference: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/ContactData/Conceptual/AddressBookProgrammingGuideforiPhone/Chapters/QuickStart.html